# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n!)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

WolframAlpha gives the evaluation as $\text{Ei}(1)-\gamma$. It does not offer a step-by-step solution. Where does this come from?

Comment: You can integrate $\sum_n \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$, and set $x$ to $1$; it takes a little bit of care with constants (which is where the $\gamma$ term comes from), but that gives you the $\mathrm{Ei}(1)$ term.

Comment: To see it, you can proceed as Steven Stadnicki said. Remark that more generally, you can develop Ei using series : $$\text{Ei}(x)=\gamma +\ln|x|+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n(n)!}$$.

Comment: @SacAndSac this is a well-known identity then I presume? Could you direct me to further reading on it and/or where I might find the proof? Thanks.

Comment: @SchrodingersDog You can find the origin of SacAndSac's equation in K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer . Chapter 37 covers the Exponential Integrals. See section 37:6.